# Watir does not trigger Jquery event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, watir

I am testing a JQuery Web application. I have a JQuery popup that I simply cannot get the submit button to fire in Watir. The same pattern is used thought the application.

I have verified the button exists and have tried click, fireEvent you name it and am out of methods to call.

Has anyone solved this?

Comment: Watir is new to me. For the curious: http://wtr.rubyforge.org/

Comment: Maybe I could help if you posted some code (popup, your Watir code...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the solution was to use and index value of 1. JQuery creates a copy of the form and all the popup items have an index of 1. The 0 index controls are on the original form.

Answer (score 1):

Which do you want ?
A. Control cursor and click "submit"
or
B. Simula te click "submit"

A:need to use Autoit and control cursor and click ,but only for windows OS.   B:execute the javascript that when clicking "submit".

If B case,there is two ways I used always.
1.execute that code in URL-bar.
ex.) @ie.link(:URL, 'javascript:<-CODE->;').click
or
Make like that module and use it by include in test case.
ex.) @ie.excute_script(<-CODE->)

```
module Watir
  class IE
   def execute_script(scriptCode)
     WIN32OLE.codepage = WIN32OLE::CP_UTF8
     window.execScript(scriptCode)
   end
   def window
     WIN32OLE.codepage = WIN32OLE::CP_UTF8
     ie.Document.parentWindow
   end
  end
```

Maybe...
I hope it help.
Sorry my poor english.
tknv/

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. [Ajax upload for jQuery demo](http://valums.com/wp-content/uploads/ajax-upload/demo-jquery.htm) is an example page. I want to upload a file using `Upload` button on the left hand side of the page.

When I click `Upload` button by hand, [file upload pop up](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/File+Uploads) appears.

When I click the button with [Watir](http://watir.com/), nothing happens.

Gary (accepted answer) helped me to find a solution:

```
browser.file_field(:index, 1).set "/path/to/file"
```